# How to use std::copy when class has `unsigned char &operator[]`

Tags: c++

I'm using a class called Buffer which has the following operator:

```
unsigned char &operator[](size_t index)
```

I'm trying to copy from it like this:

```
std::copy(buf[96], buf[96 + 32], my_uint32_t);
```

I think it doesn't work

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char; _OI = unsigned int]':
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:422:45:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = unsigned char; _OI = unsigned int]'
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:455:8:   required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = unsigned char; _OI = unsigned int]'
/home/project/SimplePacketCrafter.h:36:95:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:377:57: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned char>'
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::value_type _ValueTypeI;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:378:57: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned int>'
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_OI>::value_type _ValueTypeO;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:379:64: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned char>'
       typedef typename iterator_traits<_II>::iterator_category _Category;
                                                                ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:383:9: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned char>'
       const bool __simple = (__is_trivial(_ValueTypeI)
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       && __is_pointer<_II>::__value
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       && __is_pointer<_OI>::__value
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         && __are_same<_ValueTypeI, _ValueTypeO>::__value);
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algobase.h:386:44: error: no type named 'iterator_category' in 'struct std::iterator_traits<unsigned char>'
       return std::__copy_move<_IsMove, __simple,
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        _Category>::__copy_m(__first, __last, __result);
```

because I think I'm supposed to pass an address in the first two. There's also

```
unsigned char *index(size_t index)
```

but it also doesn't work

The methods can be seen [here](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3/blob/master/openvpn/buffer/buffer.hpp#L392)

Comment: std::copy needs iterators. If your class does not have iterators then you can't std::copy

Comment: @ÖöTiib Pointers can be iterators, so that is not an issue.

Comment: @IlCapitano pointers can be used as iterators but if class does not use pointers as iterators then it is an issue.

Comment: What is `my_uint32_t` that you pass to `std::copy`? It should be an output iterator to the array you're copying to, see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: if `my_uint32_t` is an iterator or a pointer try `std::copy(buf.index(96), buf.index(96 + 32), my_uint32_t);`

Answer (score 5):

`std:copy()` takes iterators, not references.  That is why you are getting an error.

Raw pointers can be used as iterators, provided the elements being pointed to are stored sequentially in memory.  So, assuming the buffer's `operator[]` returns a reference to elements in a single memory buffer, you can use the `&` address operator to get the memory addresses of the `char`s being referred to by `operator[]`, and then `std::copy()` can iterate between those two addresses:

```cpp
std::copy(&buf[96], &buf[96 + 32], my_uint32_t);
```

Alternatively, the buffer's `index()` and `c_index()` methods return equivilent pointers:

```cpp
std::copy(buf.index(96), buf.index(96 + 32), my_uint32_t);
```

```cpp
std::copy(buf.c_index(96), buf.c_index(96 + 32), my_uint32_t);
```